# Booster seats in taxis

Tags: children, dubai, taxis, child-safety-seats

Do I need to bring my own Booster seat for 6 year old child (120cm) when going by taxi in Dubai or will it be easy to find cars that have them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want him to sit in a booster seat you will have to bring one. But you can take the taxi without booster seat. In the Emirates (just as in many other countries) they do not really care about it. The same is true for rental cars. They only have group 1 seats (for up to 18 kilograms).